# Merging branches with Git in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge

I know there are dozens of questions on this, but I'm having trouble.  First off, I'm using Webstorm (IntelliJ) not the command line.  Second, this seems to vary by perspective.

I have my master branch, obviously.  I created a new branch called "InlineEditing". I've been working in this branch for a couple days.  There have been no changes to the master branch.  I now want to move all the changes in the current branch back to the master and resume working from there.

In Webstorm, with InlineEditing as the current branch, I tried merging using the following method but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Ie, when I then checkout the master branch, it's the old code.

[image]

So my question is, what is the proper way to "merge" my current branch back to the master?

Comment: Commit your changes to the `InlineEditing` branch, switch to `master`, and then merge `InlineEditing` into `master`.  I also use IntelliJ, but I do the heavy plumbing from the Git command line, using IntelliJ only for things like resolving merge conflicts.

Comment: Seems like that worked (even though it seems backwards to me).  Only issue is now it says my CSS files are different but when I click diff it says they're the same... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You are selecting the **local** branch master instead of the remote origin/master. And by the way, did you _fetch_?

Comment: Can you post as answer? The part I was missing is that you have to merge FROM the master.  I wish there was terminology like "Merge From".  When I hear "merge" I think my default instinct is "Merge Into"

Comment: The same with respect to what?  Make sure you are comparing agaisnt the right thing.  You probably are comparing them against the current branch, hence the diff is empty.  Instead, choose the `InlineEditing` branch for comparison, or maybe an earlier commit on `master`.

Comment: I did not do a fetch on the master because I'm the only one using the repo so it wouldn't have changed. I assume that's why you asked

Comment: If you are the only one, it doesn't matter if you fetch or not. By the way, you fetch a remote (a repository) not a branch. I don't know IntelliJ - Git integration in detail, but in Git you always merge into the current branch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The standard workflow you are following goes something like this:

```
git checkout InlineEditing
# work work work
git commit -m 'finished my work'

# now switch to master and merge the feature branch into it
git checkout master
git merge InlineEditing
# resolve any merge conflicts; IntelliJ is great for this step
```

It might be slightly counterintuitive that you have to switch to `master` in order to merge another branch into it.  Instead, you might have expected to be able to merge `InlineEditing` into `master` from the former branch.  This is just how Git works.

With regard to your original question about IntelliJ, I think there is nothing wrong with using a GUI tool for Git, provided that you know what you are doing.  I tend to do most Git operations from the command line, because I am experienced doing this and the command line is powerful.  But there are many cases where I use tools like IntelliJ.  For example, resolving merge conflicts is much easier in IntelliJ than the command line.  Also, visualizing the history of a branch can be easier using a GUI tool.

Answer (score 35):

You normally have two merge use cases.

1. **First use case** is as you have already described: there are no changes in the master branch. In this case the merge is pretty easy, see the steps on the picture below.

[image: scenario_1]

2. **Second use case** is a bit complicated: there are some changes in the master branch. You want first update the master and the InlineEdit and then merge InlineEdit into master. See the steps on the picture below.

[image: scenario_2]

Answer (score 0):

The Intellij do not have a one-click feature to merge the current branch into master, so create script to do it will be easier:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# merge current branch to master no-ff
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge "${branch}" --no-ff -m "finish the ${branch} and merge into master"
```